# Gtk3 installation

Tags: gtk3, installation-package

I'm trying to install gtk+-3.2.3 on Ubuntu natty. This is a fresh Ubuntu install with security updates only. I have not installed any new versions of gtk. I just have gtk2, that Ubuntu comes with. First I installed the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev zlib1g-dev fam libdbus-1-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev gobject-introspection libxext-dev libxrender1-dbg colordiff libcairo2-dev libtiff4-dev libpng12-dev libxft-dev libxi-devel
```

I have the following folders in: /home/mike/gtk

```
atk-2.1.5
gdk-pixbuf-2.24.1
glib-2.30.1
gtk+-3.2.3
pango-1.29.1
```

Then:

```
cd /home/mike/gtk/glib-2.30.1
./configure && make
rm -rf /home/mike/gtk/include/glib.h  /home/mike/gtk/include/gmodule.h  (glib INSTALL instructions)
```

repeat for the other folders except without the rm, in the following order:

1. atk-2.1.5
2. gdk-pixbuf-2.24.1
3. pango-1.29.1
4. gtk+-3.2.3

Before running ./configure for gtk+-3.2.3 enter this in the terminal:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/home/mike/gtk/include"
LDFLAGS="-L/home/mike/gtk/lib"
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/home/mike/gtk/lib/pkgconfig"
export CPPFLAGS LDFLAGS PKG_CONFIG_PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/mike/gtk/lib"
PATH="/home/mike/gtk/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH PATH
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/home/mike/gtk/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
```

I get the these errors when I run make on gtk+-3.2.3:

```
gdkwindow-x11.c: In function '_gdk_x11_moveresize_handle_event':
gdkwindow-x11.c:4301:9: error: 'XIEvent' undeclared (first use in this function)
gdkwindow-x11.c:4301:9: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for    each function it appears in
gdkwindow-x11.c:4301:18: error: 'ev' undeclared (first use in this function)
gdkwindow-x11.c:4301:33: error: expected expression before ')' token
gdkwindow-x11.c:4302:9: error: 'XIDeviceEvent' undeclared (first use in this function)
gdkwindow-x11.c:4302:24: error: 'xev' undeclared (first use in this function)
gdkwindow-x11.c:4302:46: error: expected expression before ')' token
gdkwindow-x11.c:4306:16: error: 'XI_Motion' undeclared (first use in this function)
gdkwindow-x11.c:4308:13: warning: implicit declaration of function '_gdk_x11_device_xi2_translate_state'
gdkwindow-x11.c:4313:16: error: 'XI_ButtonRelease' undeclared (first use in this function)
make[4]: *** [gdkwindow-x11.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/mike/gtk/gtk+-3.2.3/gdk/x11'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/mike/gtk/gtk+-3.2.3/gdk'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/mike/gtk/gtk+-3.2.3/gdk'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mike/gtk/gtk+-3.2.3'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: A less time consuming way is to upgrade (or change) the entire distribution...

Answer (score 1):

You place GTK3's source code in an arbitrary directory (into which you have write permissions). And you run `./configure` from there.

You may want to pass the `configure` scripts (of each package) a common `--prefix` to override the default of `/usr/local/` (this is needed, e.g. with `--prefix $HOME/pub`, if you cannot write under `/usr/` because you don't have root access).

Comment: What directory would you suggest and is my installation order correct?

Comment: I mention the `--prefix` argument to `configure` just now. The order of compilation is defined in GTK documentation and depends upon the facilities already available on your system.

Comment: Just finished doing it, compilation was ok, but what i'm missing in the pkg-config file.